# Using dbn.tensorflow with win10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In my code I am trying to use :

```
from dbn.tensorflow import SupervisedDBNClassification
```

I got on this error:

```
Import "dbn.tensorflow" could not be resolved
```

Any solution please?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
**Update**:
After install requirements.txt

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-794c6ozn\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-794c6ozn\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-794c6ozn\scipy\
Complete output (93 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e0ydh06f\numpy-1.23.1\setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning:

  `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
  of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
  Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
  It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
  For more details, see:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


  import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e0ydh06f\numpy-1.23.1\setup.py", line 251, in generate_cython
    - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e0ydh06f\numpy-1.23.1\setup.py", line 493, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e0ydh06f\numpy-1.23.1\setup.py", line 475, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-e0ydh06f\numpy-1.23.1\setup.py", line 258, in generate_cython
    if '--help' in sys.argv[1:] or '-h' in sys.argv[1]:
OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-794c6ozn\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-794c6ozn\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\users\pc\desktop\ali\rbfnetworks\deep-belief-network-master\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed through pip, you probably installed this library: [Decentralized-Bluetooth-Network](https://pypi.org/project/DBN/). Not what you were looking for.

You just have to follow the instruction at the [Github repository](https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network). I'll write them below:

1. First clone the repository: `git clone https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network.git`
2. Move to the cloned repository folder: `cd deep-belief-network`
3. If you are using an environment create it and activate it
4. Execute `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the requirements needed.

Comment: I am using win10 so I can't use git clone . What is the alternative?

Comment: no problem just download everything manually. You can press the green button "Code", and then, "download zip", and follow the instructions from step 2.

Comment: Could you see the update,please?

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6 as suggested by the repository ?

Comment: You can try to import the library and try it even without installing the requirements, because with that command it tries to install exactly the versions stated in the requirements.txt which may not be compatible to other versions of Python. There are not so many requirements inside that file, so just verify that you have all that modules installed and try to use the library. If this doesn’t go well (you have errors) you’ll need to switch to Python 3.6 to use that DBN

Comment: The same problem, I can not un install python 3.8.1. Can I install 3.6 with 3.8.1 ?

Comment: You can set up a new environment with a different Python version

Comment: Thanks^^ helped a lot